# Giving Items in a ListBox integer Value

Tags: vba

I'm very new to programming in Visual Basic.
Requirements:
Have a listbox with prepopulated string values.  These are seen as medical procedures
Nose Job
Eyebrow Job
Lip Botox
Face Lift

Need these values:
45.00
75.00
100.00
150.00

These each need to have a value that when selected can be calculated into other things.

I am also required to be able to add a new items to the listbox and each of these items need to have a vaule of 25.00.

Comment: well right now i have it 
Private NameValue()
Dim ProcedureCost
if listbox.selectedindex = 0 then
ProcedureCost = cint(45.00)
end if

Haven't gotten to test it yet but hopefully this works....

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub UserDidntBotherTryingItFirst()
      If listbox.value = "STUFF" Then OtherVariableYouNeedToDeclare = "SomeArbitraryNumber"
 End Sub
```